# Navigation rule not applied

Tags: jsf, navigation, xhtml

I need to navigate to different pages after a form submission depending upon the value entered by user in a comma-separated numeric field.

Following is the code for grabbing value of comsep and submit button:

```
      <h:inputText id="comsep" value="#{bean.comsep}" ></h:inputText>
      <h:commandButton value="Submit" action ="bean.func"></h:commandButton>
```

and this is the bean:

```
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;

    @ManagedBean
    public class Bean 
    {
      public String comsep;

     public Bean()
    {
    }

     public String func()
     {
        double avg = calculate();
        if (avg == 10) 
            {   return "casea";   } 
        else 
            {   return "caseb";   }
     }

    public double calculate() 
       {
       String[] pos = comsep.split(",");
       double avg = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < pos.length; i++)
       avg = avg + Integer.parseInt(pos[i]);
       avg = avg / pos.length;
       return avg;
       }


public String getComsep() {
    return comsep;
}

public void setComsep(String comsep) {
    this.comsep = comsep;
}

}
```

and this is the faces-config.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee          h  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

   <navigation-rule>
   <from-view-id>/Home.xhtml</from-view-id> 

   <navigation-case> 
   <from-action>#{bean.func}</from-action>
   <from-outcome>casea</from-outcome> 
   <to-view-id>/Page1.xhtml</to-view-id> 
   </navigation-case> 
   <navigation-case> 
   <from-action>#{bean.func}</from-action>
   <from-outcome>caseb</from-outcome> 
   <to-view-id>/Page2.xhtml</to-view-id> 
   </navigation-case> 
   </navigation-rule>
   </faces-config>
```

Expected outcome is page1 if avg == 10 else page2, but this is not happening. When I hit submit, nothing happens but home.xhtml is refreshed.

I am fairly new to JSF so sorry for rookie mistakes, if any.

Comment: So it works with an `h:inputtext`? And no need to add 'tags' in the title. Also summarize the **problem** in the title. And please start with some good non-jsf 1.2 tutorial

Comment: @Kukeltje no it does t work with h:inputtext either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `action` attribute of `commandButton` needs an EL expression not a string in order to call the method from the bean :

```
<h:commandButton ... action="#{bean.func}"></h:commandButton>
```

You could abandon the use of "faces-config.xml" file while you're using the 2.0 JSF version or newer.

Comment: thanks, but can you be more clear? I see examples all over the web which call a bean method on submit action like this - bean.func

If it needs an EL, how to do people perform navigation ?  because faces-config.xml has navigation cases written according to strings.

Comment: People make navigation in this case by specifying the destination page name directly in the string return statement of this method action, e.g : `public String func(){ ... return "somePage.xhtml"; }`.

Comment: Thanks Omar. Your solution is right. However, I was doing another silly mistake of calling the action on submit button without the curlies and #; 
action ="studentService.display()" .

Comment: You're welcome. That's an expected behavior, whenever the action method attribute value is not valid (not EL expression or not a valid page name), the page gets refreshed or nothing happened.